# Cache policy for endless image scrolling (RecyclerView, network, realm)

Tags: android, caching, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll, android-glide

I am developing RecyclerView with images and endless scrolling (network, realm db, glide, images cache)

If I scroll very far I can delete old records from my realm db.
But is it possible to delete disk cache for images corresponding to these db records (by image URL)?

What happens when I reach disk cache limit size? Will user get some warning from Android os?
Can a catch this moment in my code to drop all cache at least?

What is the professional approach for such situations?

Answer (score 0):

To delete disk cache just add below line

```
                  Glide.with(this)
                 .load("http://nuuneoi.com/uploads/source/playstore/cover.jpg")
                 .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                 .into(ivImgGlide);
```

For more detailed explanation read this [Glide vs Picasso](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)